# Is there any way to bulk many upserts to mysql db?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-aurora

The current process is doing an upsert like the code below.

However, the high number of requests seems to cause problems.

Is there a way to do it with fewer requests?

1.

```
INSERT INTO example_table (id, prop_a, prop_b) VALUES (1,1,7) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prop_a=1,prop_b=7;

-------------------------------------------------------------
id(primary key), prop_a, prop_b, prop_c
1                1       7       0
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

2. 

```
INSERT INTO example_table (id, prop_b, prop_c) VALUES (1,5,8) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prop_b=5,prop_c=8;
-------------------------------------------------------------
id(primary key), prop_a, prop_b, prop_c
1                1       5       8
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

3. 

```
INSERT INTO example_table (id, prop_a, prop_b) VALUES (7,3,3) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prop_a=3,prop_b=3;
-------------------------------------------------------------
id(primary key), prop_a, prop_b, prop_c
1                1       5       8
7                3       3       0
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO example_table (id, prop_a, prop_b, prop_c) 
SELECT 1,1,7,0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,5,0,8 UNION ALL
SELECT 7,3,3,0
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
prop_a=CASE WHEN VALUES(prop_a) = 0 
            THEN COALESCE(prop_a, 0)
            ELSE VALUES(prop_a) END,
prop_b=CASE WHEN VALUES(prop_b) = 0 
            THEN COALESCE(prop_b, 0)
            ELSE VALUES(prop_b) END,
prop_c=CASE WHEN VALUES(prop_c) = 0 
            THEN COALESCE(prop_c, 0)
            ELSE VALUES(prop_c) END;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=64a0ef6520c65de8ac7e97ea90dc40d5